# How to generate SOAP client when there are '/' characters in WSDL type definition in IRIS

Tags: intersystems-iris

We are connecting to a 3rd party SOAP web service. The wsdl looks like below

[image]

Please notice that the portType was defined as /cvpService.

Then when we are trying to use SOAP Wizard to generate a client for the service, we will encounter the following error which prevented the generation

[image]

It seems that '/cvpService'  can not be used as a valid class name (or even method name) thus the generation failed.

Thus I have 2 questions about the failure

1. Considering portType works as the definition of a SOAP operation, is it even valid to name the operation with a starting '/', do we have some restriction on the naming of portType from WSDL standard?
2. If the naming is actually valid, how can we then generate a web service client against it?

Thanks.